# Missing Activity Data for Exchange using Office 365 Management Activity API

Tags: office365

I have a prototype working of the Office 365 Management Activity API features.  I've successfully created subscriptions with webhooks and am getting data for both SharePoint and Azure AD.  However, for some reason no data is ever delivered for Exchange.  I've triple-checked and when I list subscriptions it shows Exchange just like the other two - enabled and ready to go - but no data ever shows up.  Also if I make the REST call to list notifications it also shows no data for Exchange, but I can get SharePoint and Azure AD data from it.  What else might I need to do to get these audit events for Exchange as well?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Exchange audit information that is captured:

1. Admin actions (e.g. using cmdlets to set various properties on a mailbox)
2. Owner actions (e.g. mailbox login or sending a message).

The admin audits are enabled in Exchange online by default, while owner auditing must be explicitly enabled on each mailbox.  The following article describes how to enable owner auditing:

https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn879651.aspx

Did you perform any admin actions after having created the content subscription using the API?  Have you enabled owner auditing on any mailboxes?

Comment: Thanks for the info Tom, I was just getting ready to follow up.  I just deleted and recreated the subscription for about the 5th time and the admin actions started magically working...including sending notifications for admin actions I did a couple days ago after first starting the subscription, so that is good.  As far as auditing mailboxes I didn't realize you need to do that so I will tackle that next.  Would be good to add this information to the Mgmt API docs IMO.  Thank you very much for your help!